# How can I process a list of strings where each string may be a comma-separated list of strings as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I want to convert this list

```
list = ['orange','cherry,strawberry','cucumber,tomato,coconut,avocado','apple','blueberry,banana']
```

to

```
new_list = ['orange','cherry','strawberry','cucumber','tomato','coconut','avocado','apple','blueberry','banana']
```

Is it possible to do that? Please help me!

Comment: `[y for x in thelist for y in x.split(',')]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski 
It worked bro !!! thank you so much

Comment: Your question is a variant of flattening the list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on`","`, then flatten the sub lists with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = ['orange','cherry,strawberry','cucumber,tomato,coconut,avocado','apple','blueberry,banana']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x.split(",") for x in lst))
['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'coconut', 'avocado', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 5):

Join and split!

```
>>> lst = ['orange','cherry,strawberry','cucumber,tomato,coconut,avocado','apple','blueberry,banana']
>>> ','.join(lst).split(',')
['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'coconut', 'avocado', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'banana']
```

Comment: A lot more concise than my list comprehension method, kudos.

Answer (score 4):

If the only rule is that each entry in the list can be a string representing a *single* item (without commas) or a list of items separated by commas, you can just use `str.split(',')` on each entry.

Notice the terminology there, it's important:

- The ***list*** is what you have and it contains a number of string entries;
- Each string ***entry*** is either an item or a comma-separated list of items;
- Each ***item*** is a thing you want as a separate entry in the new list.

For an entry *without* commas, `str.split` will give you a list with just that one item:

```
>>> 'cherry'.split(',')
['cherry']
```

For an item *with* commas, it will give you a list containing all the items in the entry:

```
>>> 'cherry,banana'.split(',')
['cherry', 'banana']
```

So you just need to process the list and, for each entry in the list, split it into an item list and use each of those items to construct a new list:

```
[item for entry in my_list for item in entry.split(',')]
 |  | \                  / \                          /
 |  |  \ get each entry /   \ get each item of entry /
 |  |   \______________/     \______________________/
 |  |
 +--+------> deliver all items into new list
```

You can see this working in the following transcript:

```
>>> my_list = ['orange', 'cherry,strawberry', 'apple', 'blueberry,banana']
>>> [item for entry in my_list for item in entry.split(',')]
['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'banana']
```

---

Just keep in mind that, if you want to handle entries with spaces like `'cherry, pie'`. you should probably remove extraneous spaces:

```
[item.strip() for entry in ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Extend` an accumulator list (`newvals`) while splitting on string-commas (`","`).

```py
values = ['orange','cherry,strawberry','cucumber,tomato,coconut,avocado','apple','blueberry,banana']

newvals = []
for v in values: newvals.extend(v.split(','))
print(newvals)
```

**Output**:

```
['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'coconut', 'avocado', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also flatten the list as,

```
list_1 = ['orange','cherry,strawberry','cucumber,tomato,coconut,avocado','apple','blueberry,banana', 2, 2.5]





def to_flatten(my_list, primitives=(bool, str, int, float)):
    
    flatten = []
    my_list = [stuff.split(',') if type(stuff) == str else stuff for stuff in list_1]
    
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, primitives):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(item)
    return flatten
   
print(to_flatten(list_1))
```

which gives

```
['orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'coconut', 'avocado', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'banana', 2, 2.5]

[Program finished]
```

you can change primitives as per requirement